# net.createConnection ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, econnrefused

net.createConnection always seems to give ECONNREFUSED. I did a tcpdump and don't quite know what I'm looking for.

Code:

```js
const net = require('net');
const client = net.createConnection({ port: 8124}, () => {
  // 'connect' listener.
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write('world!\r\n');
});
client.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.message);
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

Output:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8124
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8124
}
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8124
```

Link to the pcap file to view the packets [Click me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M1r3yay9stg74iUeEFKEwyYM_ra44axL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a stream-based TCP or IPC server? Or are you trying to create a simple HTTP server?

Answer (score 0):

Use a tracer like `tcpdump` to see what is actually going on.  The message, "connection *refused,"* is actually a bit misleading.  It doesn't actually mean that the host has identified you and is now refusing to talk to you.

Comment: I used wireshark to see what is happening and I don't quite know exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a server running on port 8124 of your local machine (127.0.0.1). ECONNREFUSED means you dont.